# UITextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange fires twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a table view. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I have a cell and in that cell there is UITextField. I set textfield's delegate like this: `cell.textField.delegate = self;`. I need to call my API on third character. So when user types 3 character in textfield, API is called hence `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
   if (textField.text.length >= 2) {
     NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
     substring = [substring
                 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [API CALLED WITH BLOCK WITH TEXTFIELD TEXT AS PARAMETER:substring];
 }
  return YES;
}
```

The problem is that when I type for example "abc" `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is called first time and parameter is "abc". Second after, `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is again called and my textfield has another added character which I did not type and it is always last character that is copied. So in this example, it sends "abcc". Do you know, what is the problem?

Comment: You are right, that was the case. Funy and strange at the same time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting breakpoints in that delegate method can sometimes cause the method to be fired twice. Try removing any breakpoints that are hit here or in your API method and test again.

---

This can be replicated easily. Create a new project, add a `UITextField` outlet and set the delegate to your controller. Implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` in your controller and set a breakpoint on an `NSLog` statement or something, and `return YES`. Sometimes, after telling the debugger to continue, a second keystroke will be generated and will hit your delegate method again.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a `textFieldDidChange` instead as this occurs after the text has been typed so you don't have to deal with appending strings.  From there you can just check 'text.lenght >=3' to fire your API call.

You can add the event like this:

```
[textField addTarget:self 
              action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

**EDIT:**
This code works for me. I sent up the delegate in the cell class.

```
#import "AnotherTableViewCell.h"

@implementation AnotherTableViewCell

@synthesize myTextField = _myTextField;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    // Initialization code

    _myTextField.delegate=self;

    [_myTextField addTarget:self
                  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField{
    if (textField.text.length>=3) {
        NSLog(@"Text >= 3: %@",textField.text);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: I've tried, same thing as shouldChangeCharactersInRange. It fires two times, copying last character.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you setting up your `textfield` delegate in your cell class or table class?

Comment: Either place should work, I have tested it in both.  The code @rmaddy posted works too.  You may want to check the rest of your code. Also post what your API call looks like, the issue could be there.